# Is it possible to configure jenkins to use a hardware key for sign in?

Tags: security, jenkins, yubikey

I have a usb yubikey which I use for ssh and to log in on some websites.

Can I configure my jenkins server to allow for and force sign in using a yubikey too? I feel like that would be much more secure than a password.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Comment: @CarlBruiners Not yet sadly

Comment: I found a slight work around, SASSPASS, it can use a YubiKey auth with SSO setup for Jenkins.

Comment: @CarlBruiners I am unfamiliar with sasspass, could you elaborate a bit? If you want you could post it as an answer too so I can mark it as solved if your solution is something I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have implemented https://saaspass.com/.

It uses a SAML plugin in Jenkins and then we use our mobile phones as a hardware key but if you have a YubiKey with NFC / USB-C mobile compatible you could use that in addition, so it becomes MFA.

We disabled the SMS version but saaspass does allow you to configure which authentication options you want enabled.

Comment: While not the exact kind of solution I was looking for this is a good alternative, thank you.